# Dynamic select forms

Tags: forms, ajax

I have created a custom form in Drupal 8 where I want to select a vehicle make, populate the models under the vehicle make and avail the list for selection in another field. I am stuck at the Ajax callback I have googled but haven't found a solution. I need guidance on how to use Ajax to get the desired results. My code is the following.

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('vehicle_make', 'veh');
$query->fields('veh', ['make_id','make_name']);
$results = $query->execute();
$options_makes = array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
$options_makes[$result->make_id] = $result->make_name;
}

$form['vehicle_make'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Vehicle Make'),
  '#options' => $options_makes,
  '#default' => '--Select Make --',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajaxfunction',
    'wrapper' => 'vehicle-model',
    'effect' => 'slide',
    ),
);  

$form['vehicle_model_container'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="vehicle-model">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

if ($form_state->hasValue('vehicle_make')) {
  $vehicle_make = $form_state->getValue('vehicle_make');
  $subquery = \Drupal::database()->select('vehicle_model', 'md');
  $subquery->join('vehicle_make', 'mak', 'md.make_id = mak.make_id');
  $subquery->fields('md', ['model_id','model_name']);
  $subquery->condition('md.make_id', $vehicle_make);
  $results = $subquery->execute(); 
  $model_options = array();

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $model_options[$result->model_id] = $result->model_name;
  }

  $form['vehicle_model_container']['model'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Vehicle Model'),
    '#options' => $model_options,
  );

  function ajaxfunction(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['vehicle_model_container'];
  }
```

Comment: I think the ajax callback is OK, you only need to call it as a class method `'callback' => '::ajaxfunction',` see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192060/ajax-callback-function-is-un-callable

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return fetched array as result, in Drupal ajax the return value from the ajax function actually overwrites the wrapper, so you've got to set `$form['vehicle_model']['#options']` with fetched value and the return this piece of form (`$form['vehicle_model']`) as function return value. so the code will be something like this :

```
function _ajaxfunction(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $vehicle_make = $form_state->getValue('vehicle_make');
  $subquery = \Drupal::database()->select('vehicle_model', 'md');
  $subquery->join('vehicle_make', 'mak', 'md.make_id = mak.make_id');
  $subquery->fields('md', ['model_id','model_name']);
  $subquery->condition('md.make_id', $vehicle_make);
  $results = $subquery->execute(); $options_models = array();
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $options_models[$result->model_id] = $result->model_name;
  }
  $form['vehicle_model']['#options'] = $options_models;
  return $form['vehicle_model'];
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code but it doesn't work. The models select field doesn't appear even when a make is selected.